# Transform Indented Text (Markdown) Into Codeblock

Tags: javascript

I am making something that needs to transform indented paragraphs into a codeblock using markdown. Here's what I mean:

```
This is normal text, nothing to worry about.
    const normalFunction = (...args) => {
      return ...args;
    }
Please turn ^ into codeblock. Thx
```

I would like that to be transformed to

````
This is normal text, nothing to worry about.
```js
const normalFunction = (...args) => {
  return ...args;
}
```
Please turn ^ into codeblock. Thx
````

And every other occurrence like this. I have tried many different RegEx for this, and found one which I thought would work, but it was for PHP and I wasn't able to transform it to a JavaScript RegEx.

It's fine to use ES6, what's more, I recommend it, as it has many more features.
The RegEx I currently use is `/( {4}[\n\r\s\S]+;)/gi`, but it selects everything if there are multiple codeblocks, and doesn't select some things if it's a comment and it doesn't end with `;`.

Comment: Is there is a reason you don't run the whole text segment through a markdown compiler? If there is no special formatting going on, then it should just return the text as it was before. 

I built something like this before and used the `marked` library. https://github.com/chjj/marked

Comment: @Falk I get that markdown from parsing some HTML with `marked`, so I hadn't thought to run it through the compiler again. I'll try it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: So I tried to do what you recommended, but now all the 4 space-indentation for the codeblocks got deleted :|

Comment: Hm, I don't know if running it through marked twice is a good idea. Do you have a bigger code example? You said you are getting the markdown from parsing HTML. What is your beginning data like?

Comment: @Falk I get the data from the NodeJS API docs, at https://nodejs.org/api/all.html . An example of the data can be found as the "description" field in any module in https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.json, which is where I get the HTML from (description)
Sorry if that sounded a bit confusing...

Comment: Sorry, I totally confused everything. I am using the `to-markdown` module, because I need to convert the HTML to Markdown. I'll try to do something like `toMarkdown(marked(toMarkdown(html)))` and see if that makes any difference

Comment: I am so sorry, @Falk, for wasting your time. I fixed this by adding a filter to the `pre` tag, as `to-markdown` allows filters. Thanks for trying to help, though. Once again, I apologize.

Comment: Can you post an answer below? It is usually encouraged to post answers as answers. Self-answering is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is my late self-answer.

I was using NodeJS and the `to-markdown` NPM module.
Apparently, `to-markdown` has support for filters to convert an HTML tag to whatever you want.
I added a filter for the tag `pre` so it would add the markdown needed for a code block.

This is my final code:

```
return toMarkdown(str, {
  gfm: true,
  converters: [{
    filter: "pre",
    replacement: content => `\`\`\`${lang.toLowerCase()}\n${content.replace(/<\/?code( \S+)?>/g, ``)}\n\`\`\``,
  }],
});
```

I used a few RegEx's there to replace the `<code lang=##>` and `</code>` tags inside the `pre` tag with nothing.

I hope this helped. Sorry, I didn't know if we had to write an answer for ourselves or not.

---

**EDIT**: I realize if this has nothing to do with RegEx, and I apologize if that's what you were looking and hoping for.